# Use boolean variable in several components

Tags: angular, typescript

how can I use a boolean variable initialized in a component in other components ?
Let me explain :
I have a boolean variable 'flash' that I initialize in my component 'chat-threads'.

```
<div class="flash-signal">
  Signal visuel :
  <input type="radio" name="flashsignal" id="flashsignal1" checked="checked" (click)="flashSignal()">
  <label for="flashsignal1">Oui</label>
  <input type="radio" name="flashsignal" id="flashsignal2" (click)="notFlashSignal()">
  <label for="flashsignal2">Non</label>
</div>
```

Other code :

```
export class ChatThreadsComponent implements OnInit {

flash = true;

constructor(public threadsService: ThreadsService,
          public messagesService: MessagesService,
          public boxService: BoxService) {
  this.threads = threadsService.orderedThreads;
}

ngOnInit(): void {
   this.flash = true;
}

notFlashSignal(): void {
  this.flash = false;
}

flashSignal(): void {
    this.flash = true;
}
}
```

I would like to be able to read the value of this variable in another component 'chat-window' in order to be able to display a visual signal or not.

```
<div [ngClass]="{'notification-message-unread' : !box.thread.lastMessage.isRead && flash}">
```

Do I have to implement this variable in my component?

EDIT :

```
export class Box {
id: string;
thread: Thread;
discussion: Observable<Message[]>;
flash: boolean;

constructor(id?: string,
            thread?: Thread,
            messages?: Observable<Message[]>,
            flash?: boolean
) {
    this.id = id || uuid();
    this.thread = thread || null;
    this.discussion = messages;
    this.flash = flash || true;
}
```

}

Component :

```
<div [ngClass]="{'notification-message-unread' : !box.thread.lastMessage.isRead && !box.flash}">
```

Comment: Whenever it comes to sharing of data, using service is the way to go.

Comment: @CozyAzure 
I published my post. Do you advise me to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When two components are not having any parent child relationship, the best way is a shared [service](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection) injected into the constructors of A and B.

**component A:**

```
constructor(private sharingService: SharingService) { }
```

**component B:**

```
constructor(private sharingService: SharingService) { }
```

**Service**:

```
import { Injectable, } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()

flash: boolean = true;

constructor() {}
```

You can use it in components using `this.sharingService.flash`. For complete reference [see this.](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)

Comment: OK, thanks. I published my post. Is that what must be done?

How do I initialize this variable to true by default ?

Comment: Yes, this is the right way to share a variable between two independent components. By default value you can give in the service like I have mentioned in my example.

Answer (score 1):

Use @Input decorator to move your values to child component or pass it through services.
In child:

```
@Input() name: any;
```

then in parent component

```
<child [name]="farrukh"></child>
```

More can be read about [services](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service):

Comment: Yes but in my case, both components have no inheritance

Comment: Then service is a better solution for you